# Regex to get text between first and last inverted commas

Tags: regex

The text is `-"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"The_Above_Ground_Sound"_of_Jake_Holmes":hey`. I need regex to get `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"The_Above_Ground_Sound"_of_Jake_Holmes`. I tried to write `\"(.*?)\"` but failed since the inverted commas are nested. I need to get last occurrence of " at last ending part.

I think I need negative look ahead solution but not sure.

Comment: I tried something and created - \"(.*?)(\")(?!.*\"). This is working. Let me know if we can have something more clean.

Comment: remove the `?` to turn the match greedy. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA3oN2/1)

Comment: What is the language or tool?

Comment: @Tensibai, Mine was nice example of stitching with sword while we need needle. Thanks it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"(.*)"
```

This grabs everything between two double quotation marks and it grabs in a greedy fashion. This means that it will try and match as much text as possible between the two quotation marks.

Comment: why escaping the quotes ? they're not a special char in regex, could depend on the language used, but as long as we don't know it, there's no reason to introduce backslashes.

Comment: Completely right, I was just assuming they needed to be escaped in the interpreter used as the example contained escapes. Will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Actually what the OP needs based on his request is:

```
(?<=").*(?=") 
# match only the contents without the external double quotes "..." ->
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"The_Above_Ground_Sound"_of_Jake_Holmes
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL0vE4/1)